# Show an ideal is a finitely generated projective module via a split exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, exact-sequence

> Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that the mapping $f:I\otimes_R\operatorname{Hom}_R (I,R)→R$ defined (on the generators) by $f(i\otimes α)=α(i)$ for all $i∈I$ and $α∈\operatorname{Hom}_R (I,R)$ is onto. Show that $I$ is a finitely generated projective $R$-module.

Here is the hint I have been given: Show there is a split exact sequence $0→K→F→I→0$, where $F$ is a finitely generated free $R$-module.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried something along this line: $1=\alpha_1(i_1)+\cdots+\alpha_m(i_m)$, and see whether the morphism $\oplus^mR\to I, r_1\oplus\cdots\oplus r_m\mapsto\sum_{k=1}^m r_ki_k$ is onto and split?

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried that, but what you have wrote will imply that $1\in I$, and so $I=R$? Shouldn't $I$ be arbitrary?

Comment: If $f$ is onto, you do have such a relation. On another hand, there's no reason why $\alpha(i)$  should belong to $I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the surjectivity of the evaluation map $\mathrm{Hom}_R(I,R)\otimes_R I\to R$, you can find $R$-linear maps $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m:I\to R$ and elements $i_1,\dots,i_m\in I$ such that
$$\alpha_1(i_1)+\cdots+\alpha_m(i_m)=1$$
Consider the map $\phi:R^{\oplus m}\to I,(r_1,\dots,r_m)\mapsto r_1i_1+\cdots+r_mi_m$. This map is surjective. Indeed, write $\rho_k=\alpha_k(i_k)$ for $k=1,\dots,m$. Then, if $i\in I$,
$$i=i\cdot 1=\sum_{k=1}^m i\rho_k=\sum_{k=1}^m i\alpha_k(i_k)=\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k(i)i_k=\phi(\alpha_1(i),\dots,\alpha_m(i))$$
This furthermore shows that
$$\psi=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m):I\to R^{\oplus m}$$
is a splitting: $\phi\circ\psi=\mathrm{id}_I$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. can I ask about your notation $R^{⊕m}$? is that means the $m$ copies direct sum of $R$, $⊕_m R$ ?

Comment: Yes, it means $R\oplus R\oplus\cdots\oplus R$, $m$ times.

Comment: I guess the free module $F$ in the exact in the hint provided is $F=⊕_m R$, so may I ask if I need to find the $K$ that listed in the hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $K$ is the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: But you do not really have to find $K$. The surjection $F \to I$ splits, hence $I$ is a direct summand of a free module and thus projective.